# after kernel-upgrade: missing keyboard events

Tags: linux, keyboard, mouse, udev

After a kernel upgrade (3.19 to 4.4) key map of my keyboard mouse buttons was partially broken.

While others still work as intended, the middle button just fires after key release (then both keydown and keyup).

Tested:

```
sudo cat /dev/input/event22
sudo evtest /dev/input/event22
sudo showkey
```

Suggestions? Is there a way to go to a deeper layer than "/dev/input/event22"?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a working solution:

```
sudo cat /dev/usb/hiddev0 | hexdump
```

did capture the keydown/keypress event!

I didn't dive into the hiddev API, but recognized counter prefixes and repeating suffix values per line. Since they don't differ between keydown and keyup I implemented a toggle function in python (needs read permissions to /dev/usb/hiddev0):

```
import os
import time
import pyautogui as pa

DEVPATH = "/dev/usb/hiddev0"
BTNHEX = "F200A0FF00000000" # first/unique hex value of ThinkPad middle button
NEWKEY = "ctrlleft" # mapping target

def byteToHex(byteStr):
  return "".join(["%02X" % ord(b) for b in byteStr]).strip()

def waitForPathExists(DEVPATH):
  while not os.path.exists(DEVPATH): time.sleep(0.5)

def watchHandleDev(dev, isPressed):
  byteStr = os.read(dev, 8)
  currentHex = byteToHex(byteStr[:8])
  if currentHex == BTNHEX:
    pa.keyUp(NEWKEY) if isPressed else pa.keyDown(NEWKEY)
    return not isPressed
  return isPressed

def handleDevUnavailable(dev):
  print "device '%s' not readable, waiting" % DEVPATH
  os.close(dev)
  waitForPathExists(DEVPATH)
  print "device '%s' found, reopening" % DEVPATH
  return os.open(DEVPATH, os.O_RDONLY)

def main():
  dev = os.open(DEVPATH, os.O_RDONLY)
  isPressed = False
  while True:
    try:
      isPressed = watchHandleDev(dev, isPressed)
    except OSError, err:
      print "err", err
      if err.errno == 5: dev = handleDevUnavailable(dev)
```